# How to get background of light box to fill the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a lightbox effect affecting one of my buttons. Now it works fine, the only problem is the background is suppose to be dark black. However it only effects a certain bit of the pannel rather than the whole body.

So the codepen [Example](http://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/qsCkF)

Everything goes black. Which is what i am trying to make, however on mine it actually just goes black on a certain part.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><b>Product</b></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="Image/coconut.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <a id="show-panel" class="btn btn-success btn-block btnrec" href="#">View product</a>
                    <div id="lightbox-panel">
    <h2>Lightbox Panel</h2>
    <p>You can add any valid content here.</p>
    <p align="center"><a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
</div>
<div id="lightbox"></div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Lightbox background */
#lightbox {
  display:none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
}
/* Lightbox panel with some content */
#lightbox-panel {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  width:700px;
  height: 700px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
  border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#show-panel").click(function() {
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
  });
  $("a#close-panel").click(function() {
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
  })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/147/)

So again just want everything to be black and the light box panel to attention

Thanks

Comment: That's because you haven't added jquery. Link it!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/145/ that is a fiddle example

Comment: In that Fiddle link, the `click` handler is pointing to an element with an id of `show-panel`, which doesn't exist. The button has the following classes `btn btn-success btn-block btnrec`

Comment: This works http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/9LFKV/146/

Comment: @Akshay i tried but it did not work

Comment: @user3466372 It works if you click the text, not the button.

Comment: @NickR but thats what i mean, i need it to work when u click on the button , not the text

Comment: Ok i updated the question a little :) makes it easier to understand

Comment: Use `position:fixed` on the background?

Comment: @swervo not sure if that works

Comment: @NiZa please could you post ur finding so i can see, thanks

Comment: But this wont affect anything to do when its mobile version?

Comment: Nope this works for every device.

Comment: Bootstrap uses `position:fixed` for their modals

Comment: Ok and sorry 1 more question, how do i create the "X" thing so i can put it in the top right hand corner , that would be great if i could do that

Comment: Thank u also again for all the help and taking ur time x